# falling delay inverters VLSI CMOS

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos, inverter, delay, vlsi

How do I obtain the falling delay driving by signal A:

Data:

```
NMOS W/L=1/.35

PMOS W/L=2/.35

Resistor-NMOS= 1/2 and PMOS5 Kohms.micro 

Cgate=Cdif=4/3fF/microm

Cmetal-ground=100fF

Cmetal-metal=39fF

Rmetal 800 ohms
```

1.-When B is not switching

2,-When B is switching simultaneously in the same direction than A

3.-When B is switching simultaneously opposite to A
[image: circuit delay]

Comment: Thank you Null, next time i will try to be more specific on the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your aim is to have falling slope of inverters appear later than rising slope? If so, if it is available **reduce W/L ratio of NMOS transistor and increase W/L ratio of PMOS transistor**.

Capacitances on the output are seen both by NMOS and PMOS transistors.

Comment: I am confused on the switching part the two inverter(A and B) are connected and each one has its own capacitance(Cmetal-ground=100fF and Cmetal-metal=39fF, i guess?). So the part where i am confuse is what formula should i need to applied when it is switching. Sorry i did not get this comment "reduce W/L ratio of NMOS transistor and increase W/L ratio of PMOS transistor."

Comment: ​​
You have 4 cases when inverters switch their states:
1. inverters A and B switch from 0 to 1 at the same time
2. inverters A and B switch from 1 to 0 at the same time
3. inverter A switches from 0 to 1 and inverter B switches from 1 to 0
4. inverter A switches from 1 to 0 and inverter B switches from 0 to 1

In my opinion, for cases 1 and 2, capacitance Cmetal-metal should be seen as 39 fF so nothing special happens.
For cases 3 and 4, capacitance Cmetal-metal is larger due to Miller phenomenon. So rising/falling edges are longer. Inverters need more time to go from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.

Comment: I won't give you exact formula. Just use a simulator. The good thing is to now what is going to happen. For exact calculations use a simulator.

"reduce W/L ratio of NMOS transistor and increase W/L ratio of PMOS transistor."
Inverter is constructed from NMOS and PMOS transistors. To reduce W/L ratio means to reduce the width (called W) of a transistor or to increase its length (called L). To increase means the opposite - increase the width or reduce the length.

Comment: I am working on it, thank you for your comments, it has been useful.

Comment: @TechStudent No problem. Please notify if you succeed.

Comment: Today i  was working with another circuit related to improve the cock frequency rate, when i get the result i will notify it. i hope i can be succeed.